# Read in a JSON file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read in a JSON file into python, but a test script I am running after my code is giving me an error.

Here is my code to read in the JSON file when my function is called.  The data file is saved on the same server and there aren't any known issues with that file.

```
def read_json(data_file):
    '''
A function which reads in a JSON file.


Parameters
-------
data_file: a string, the name of the file to be read in.


Returns
--------

data: a Python list containing the read in data from the json file.

'''
    with open(data_file) as fin:
        data = json.load(fin)

    return data
```

Here is the test script that calls the function.

```
data_file = './data/dow_jones.json'
data = read_json(data_file)
```

Here is the error I am receiving from the previous call.

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Your error indicates that the path you are passing to the `json.load` function does not contain a valid JSON formatted file.

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't realize I left that out.  I have added the example above.

Comment: "The data file is saved on the same server and there aren't any known issues with that file." Well, the json decoder is indicating *that there is a problem* with that file, and I'm inclined to believe it.

Comment: When I open the JSON file on the server, here is all that is in that file.
"./data/dow_jones.json"

Comment: can you use `cat ./data/dow_jones.json | head` on the server? What does it give you?

Comment: It doesn't appear to return anything

Comment: @Thomas Then the file is probably empty. There's nothing to read.

Comment: Then it appears your file is empty. Which makes sense, given the error message indicates it happens at character 0. what does `wc -c ./data/dow_jones.json` give you?

Comment: Actually, it appears I was looking at the wrong file in a different directory.  When I open the correct file, it is blank.

Comment: 0 ./data/dow_jones.json    is what I get from that

Comment: @Thomas yeah, the file is empty.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense then.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JSONDecodeError` suggests that either the file is corrupt or has not been opened in the right mode.

- Check that the first few lines of the file look like JSON. You could also paste the contents of the file into a [JSON validator](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=json%20validator).
- Check that the file encoding matches python's default. If the file is `encoding="utf-8"` with a BOM and you are on Windows and trying to read it as `encoding="latin-1252"`, it may cause this error. You might need to specify an encoding when opening the file, such as `with open(data_file, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')`.